# Using inequalities to find vertices of a polytope

Tags: convex-analysis, computational-mathematics, polytopes

Consider a set $C$ of vectors of integers $x\in\mathbb N^d$ satisfying

$$
\begin{align}
\forall\ i=1..d   & \ \ [0 \leq \ell_i \leq x_i \leq u_i]\\
\forall\ i=1..d-1 & \ \ [x_{i+1} \leq x_i]
\end{align}
$$

where $\ell_i, u_i,\ i=1..d$ are bounds satisfying $\forall i=1..d-1\ [\ell_{i+1} \leq \ell_{i}]$ so that the set is nonempty. This is a convex polytope (ignoring the $\in\mathbb N^d$ part), and I'm interested in finding its vertices.

My current approach is:

1. Enumerate all integer vectors/points in the "hyperrectangle" from the first condition
2. Drop all points not satisfying the second condition
3. Pass the set of points to a convex-hull finder

But I suspect there is as more straightforward way to find these vertices, given the simple structure of the problem.

Comment: Less importantly, it seems likely that I won't have the option of using a convex-hull finder in the software I'm using (Stata, which only has it for $d=2$). I'm going to be using this in a programming a loop, but math.SE seemed like a better place for this than SO.

Comment: It seems that you did the right choice asking your question at MSE instead of SO. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

Let $x=(x_1,\dots,x_d)\in C$. We shall call an index $i$ *fixed* provided $x_i=\ell_i$ or $x_i=u_i$.

**Proposition.** A vector $x=(x_1,\dots,x_d)\in C$ is a vertex of $C$ iff for each index $i$ there exists a fixed index $j$ such that $x_i=x_j$.

*Proof.* First of all we remark that a point $x$ is a vertex of $C$ iff there exist no different points $y,z\in C$ and a number $0<\lambda<1$ such that $x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda) z.$

*Necessity.* Suppose that there exists an index $i$ such that there exists no fixed index $j$ such that $x_i=x_j$. Let $j_1$ be a largest fixed index smaller than $i$, or $0$ is there is no such index. Let $j_2$ be a smallest fixed index larger than $i$, or $d+1$ is there is no such index. Define points $y,z\in\Bbb N$ as follows. For each $j$ put $y_j=x_j-1$ and $z_j=x_j-1$, if $j_1<j<j_2$, and put 
$y_j=z_j=x_j$, otherwise. It is easy to check that $y,z\in C$ and $x=(y+z)/2$, so $x$ is not a vertex of $C$.

*Sufficiency.* Suppose that $x$ is not a vertex of $C$. Then there exist points $y,z\in C$ and a number $0<\lambda<1$ such that $x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda) z.$ Since $y\ne z,$ there exists an index $i$ such that $y_i\ne z_i$. Suppose that there exists a fixed index $j$ such that $x_i=x_j$. Since the index $j$ is fixed, $y_j=z_j=x_j=x_i$. Suppose that $j\le i$. Since $y,z\in C$, $y_i\le y_j$ and $z_i\le z_j$. Then $x_i=\lambda y_i+(1-\lambda) z_i\le x_i$. Therefore $y_i=z_i=x_i,$ a contradiction. The case $j\ge i$ is considered similarly.$\square$

Comment: The proposition seems to check out, based on my simple implementation here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8k2cfjysgsjo1l3/chk_convhulln.r?dl=0 There is one step in the sufficiency argument that seems off to me. ($y$ and $z$ must differ in at least one dimension, $i$, but you use the property that they differ _only_ in $i$ when saying $y_j=z_j=x_j=x_i$). I may be wrong, of course. Thanks again!

Comment: Since $ 0<\lambda<1$, if $y_j\ne z_j,$ then $x_j$ is an interior point of the segment $[y_j,z_j]$. So one of $\{y_j,z_j\}$ is greater than $x_j$, and the other is less than $x_j$. But this is impossible, because the index $j$ is *fixed*, therefore $x_j$ is an *endpoint* the segment $[\ell_j,u_j]$ of admissible values for $j$-th coordinate of a point of $C$.

Comment: Concerning the algorithm. It seems too complicated, especially the search through all partitions. So I hope that there is more effective algorithm, maybe even such that yields no duplicates. Unfortunately, now I see no good algorithms, but you may try to  ask about them at SO.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Instead of looking through the partitions (as I had imagined before), I ended up enumerating $x\in(\cup_i \{\ell_i,u_i\})^d$ and then crossing off vectors (i) not in $C$ and then (ii) not meeting the criterion you propose. That enumeration step will not scale well, but should be okay for the $d$ I'm facing at the moment, so I'll defer asking on SO.